# How to search for multiple items in Postgres Json

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a json column called items that stores data as json in Postgres DB, it stores the data as in a single row

```
[
   {
      "item_code":"UMI MAIZE Box (10.0 PC)",
      "name":"5e0648a9e5",
      "uom":null
   },
   {
      "item_code":"Fadge Chocolate Box (4.0 Box)",
      "name":"d805f9bb9d",
      "uom":null
   }
]
```

I have query that looks for a single Item code that shows the results

```
select items->>'item_code' from pricing_rule where items::jsonb @> '[{"item_code": "Fadge Chocolate Box (4.0 Box)"}]';
```

How can I write a query that looks for all items in item_code alone without passing

```
[{"item_code": "Fadge Chocolate Box (4.0 Box)"}]'
```

and pass only the item_codes like

```
("Fadge Chocolate Box (4.0 Box)", "UMI MAIZE Box (10.0 PC)")
```

and only use the in command something similar to the query

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column type is JSONB (which it should be) first flatten the JSON array using `jsonb_array_elements` and `cross join lateral`.

```sql
select * 
from the_table 
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(jitems) as t(item)
where item ->> 'item_code' in 
      ('Fadge Chocolate Box (4.0 Box)','UMI MAIZE Box (10.0 PC)');
```

If you need the query to be parameterized then this would be easier

```sql
select * from  
the_table 
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(jitems) as t(item)
where item ->> 'item_code' = 
      any ('{Fadge Chocolate Box (4.0 Box),UMI MAIZE Box (10.0 PC)}'::text[]);
```

where the search string becomes a parameter.

Comment: Hi @Stefanov.sm is  jsonb_array_elements() function is expensive? in terms of performance?

Comment: Not the function really but the process of flattening might be very expensive. So it makes sense to first filter the rows that are to be flattened within the `where` clause. BTW why don't you try a normalized data design? It will make things a lot easier and performant.